# Angular velocity - from inclined to horizontal plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, energy-conservation

Assume a uniform ball ($m,\ R,\ I=\frac25mR^2$), experiencing pure rolling on both horizontal and inclined planes.

If we imagine a point $A$ at the very start of the inclined plane, we can show that the angular velocity $\omega_1$ the instant the ball starts climbing the inclined plane is given by:

$$\omega_1=\left(\frac{5\cos\theta+2}7\right)\omega_0\tag1$$

[image: roller before climbing inclined plane]

This can be derived from the conservation of AM about point $A$

$$L_i=L_f\iff R_A\times mv_0+I_c\omega_0=I_a\omega_1\\
\implies mv_0R\cos\theta+\frac25mR^2\omega_0=\left(\frac25mR^2+mR^2\right)\omega_1\\
\implies\omega_1=\left(\frac{5\cos\theta+2}7\right)\omega_0\tag2$$

What is the angular velocity $\omega_2$ when the ball is back at the horizontal plane? The correct expression of $\omega_2$ is supposed to be:

$$\omega_2=\left(\frac{5\cos\theta+2}7\right)^2\omega_0\tag3$$

Conservation of energy gives that when the ball has reached $y_\text{max}$ and rolled back to point $A$, then the angular velocity must have the same magnitude as $\omega_1=\left(\frac{5\cos\theta+2}7\right)\omega_0$.

In the transition from the inclined to the horizontal plane, I presume that the instantaneous axis of rotation will be the contact point between the ball and the horizontal plane. I am not sure how to write down the correct equation for the conservation of AM in this transition.

Answer (score 0):

In the moment of contact you have two touching points, so it shifts from one to the other and $\omega_1=\omega_2$ for the first moment.[image: image of touching]